# Keep the value on dropdown list after submitting form

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller

How do I display the selected option on drop down list after submitting form? It always displays the first option.

```
     <form id="myform" >
        <label for="selectoption">Birimler</label>
        <select id="SelectOption" name="SelectOption" onchange="$('#myform').submit();" value="a">
            <option>Seçiniz</option>
            <option id="aYo" value="Yonetim">Yönetim</option>
            <option id="aAr"  value="Arge">ARGE</option>
            <option id="aDe"  value="Depo">Depo/Sevkiyat</option>
            <option id="aIK"  value="IKID">İnsan Kaynakları/İdari İşler</option>        
        </select>
    </form>
```

Comment: You can use `preventDefault()` to prevent default actions.

Comment: @divyeshmakvana How can I submit then, I don't get it at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used `viewbag`

```
<select style="width:100px" id="SelectOption" name="SelectOption" value="a">
       
        <option>@Html.Label("-",(string)ViewBag.Name,new {@class = "mylabel" })</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the value in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) like:

```
localStorage.setItem('selectOption', $(#SelectOption).val());
```

then your browser will remember this value even after page reload (form send), then you can fill your form by getting the value

```
$(#SelectOption).val(localStorage.getItem('selectOption'))
```

Comment: where should i use them? before or after the select

Comment: You can set value (first line) in $(#SelectOption).change function, and get it (second line) anywhere after page load. You can put it anywhere in js in $(document).ready(function(){ HERE })

Comment: unfortunately couldn't make it work

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function getOption() {
        selectElement = document.querySelector('#selectoption');
        output = selectElement.value;
        document.querySelector('.output').textContent = output;
    }
    </script>
```

or try this:

```
selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].value
```

selectedIndex---It is used to set or get the index of the selected  element in the collection.

length---It is read-only property that is used to get the number of  elements in the collection.

Comment: couldn't make it work

Answer (score -1):

The preventDefault() method cancels the event if it is cancelable, meaning that the default action that belongs to the event will not occur.

For example, this can be useful when:

Clicking on a "Submit" button, prevent it from submitting a form
Clicking on a link, prevent the link from following the URL
Kindly check this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp#:%7E:text=The%20preventDefault()%20method%20cancels,link%20from%20following%20the%20URL).

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#SelectOption').change(function (e) {

        console.log($( "#SelectOption" ).val())
        let SelectOptionValue = $( "#SelectOption" ).val()
        console.log("click",SelectOptionValue)

        // $('#myform').submit();

        $( "#SelectOption" ).val("Depo")
        console.log($( "#SelectOption" ).val())
        console.log("click")
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```